# Can't redirect to https and server static files on http on nginx

Tags: caching, nginx, https, static

I can't get the content of /resources to be delivered directly through http (with caching etc) and everything else (/, /anything) to be redirected to https. This is the config as it stands now.

> ```
> location /resources/ {
>         access_log off;
>         autoindex on;
>         expires 3d;
>         ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in o$
>         ## fell swoop.
>         tcp_nodelay off;
>         ## Set the OS file cache.
>         open_file_cache max=3000 inactive=120s;
>         open_file_cache_valid 45s;
>         open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
>         open_file_cache_errors off;
>         root /usr/share/nginx/www/resources;
>         try_files $uri $uri/;
> }
> location / {
>         rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host$request_uri redirect;
>         if ($http_host !~ "^www\."){
>         rewrite ^(.*)$ https://www.$http_host$request_uri redirect;
>         }
> }
> ```

Comment: what domains do you want working, ones with `www` or without `www`?

Comment: both. My DNS handles with/out www.

Comment: I asked because you have a redirection from non-www to www, so I guessed you have a preferred domain

Answer (score 0):

First remove the line **try_files $uri $uri/** from your location /resources/.

The way you define your *location /resources* block requires that the url request path ends with a trailing **/**

In other words requesting

```
your-domain/resources
```

will not work but

```
your-domain/resources/
```

will work.